# Get row from matrix of functions

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I have code that looks something like this

```
x = [100 0 0]

f = @(c,x) [v1(c,x) 0 0];
X = rk4(x, f, a, b, c);
x = X(end,:);

f = @(c,x) [v2(c,x) s1(c,x) 0]; 
X = [ X; rk4(x, f, a, b, c) ];
x = X(end,:);

f = @(c,x) [v2(c,x) s2(c,x) r(c,x)]; 
X = [ X; rk4(x, f, a, b, c) ];
x = X(end,:);
```

That is, at each step, I just change what three functions f is, so I was wondering if it would be possible to do something like this:

```
f = @(c,x) [v1(c,x) 0 0; v2(c,x) s1(c,x) 0; v2(c,x) s2(c,x) r(c,x)]
x = [100 0 0]
X = []    
for i=1:3
    X = [X ; rk4(x, f(i,:), a, b, c)]
    x = X(end,:);
end
```

I know it's not possible to do exactly what I did (apparently f(i,:) simply returns the matrix of functions f, not the row of functions at row #i.

Comment: What are `rk4`,`v1`, `v2`, `s1`, `s2` and `r`? Read how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, there is command called `reshape`. Just give the size as per need.

```
rowvector = reshape(your_matrix,[1,m*n])
```

I hope this should do the trick.

Comment: oh 
thanks for telling I didn't knew  



In Matlab there is command called reshape just give the size as per need

rowvector = reshape(your_matrix,[1,m*n])

i hope this should do the trick